# Shadcn Select won't reset on form.reset() call (react-hook-form)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form

I'm using the Shadcn UI Select component inside of a FormField component (so using zod for validation and react-hook-form to manage form state).

The form component resets upon submission like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    form.reset(defaultValues);
    // (...)
}, [form.formState.submitCount])
```

which causes the form values (saved in formState) to reset (so the default values get submitted with next submission), but the Select fields still display previously chosen items.
Here's the FormField component (they're dynamically generated):

```
<FormField
   control={form.control}
   key={position}
   name={position}
   render={({ field }) => (
      <FormItem className="my-5">
         <FormLabel>{position} place</FormLabel>
            <Select onValueChange={(value) => onSelectDancer(field, value)}>
               <FormControl>
                  <SelectTrigger>
                     <SelectValue
                        placeholder="Please select a dancer / couple"
                        {...field}
                     />
                  </SelectTrigger>
               </FormControl>
            <SelectContent>
               {dancers
                  .filter(dancer => (!Object.values(selectedDancers).includes(dancer.id.toString()) || selectedDancers[position] === dancer.id.toString()))
                  .map(dancer => (
                     <SelectItem
                        key={dancer.id.toString()}
                        value={dancer.id.toString()}
                     >{Object.values(dancer).join(', ')}</SelectItem>
                ))}
                <SelectItem key='blank' value='none'>None</SelectItem>
              </SelectContent>
           </Select>
        </FormItem>
     )}
/>
```

and here's the onValueChange handler:

```
function onSelectDancer(field: any, dancerId: string) {
    field.onChange(dancerId);
    setSelectedDancers({...selectedDancers, [field.name]: dancerId})
}
```

I've even managed to locate the nested component that's holding the displayed item's value (SelectProvdier - as displayed in the screenshot from ReactDevTools), but I have no idea how to clear it...
[ReactDevTools screenshot showing the SelectProvider component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kgYw.png)

Here's the whole form component: https://github.com/emdoem/hatful-of-pears/blob/master/components/ScoreInput.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can works

Add react hook form reset function

```
reset({
   selectFieldName: undefined
})
```